# Table row and header not aligned properly?

Tags: html, css, gsp

I'm dynamically adding table header and table body with vertical scroll bar to display results, the problem I'm facing here is table header lines and row lines not aligned... Here is my code:

GSP code:

${column}

${row[column]}

And my css code:

```
table.scroll {
    /* width: 100%; */ /* Optional */
    /* border-collapse: collapse; */
    border-spacing: 0;
    border: 2px solid black;
}

table.scroll tbody,
table.scroll thead { display: block; }

thead tr th {
    height: 30px;
    width:15px;
    line-height: 30px;
    /* text-align: left; */
}

table.scroll tbody {
    height: 400px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

tbody { border-top: 2px solid black; }

tbody td, thead th {
     width:15px;
    /* Optional */
    border-right: 1px solid black;
    /* white-space: nowrap; */
}

tbody td:last-child, thead th:last-child {
    border-right: none;
}
```

Any suggestions around would be appreciated..

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you're going to add a `thead` element, you need to add a `tbody` element for the rows beneath it, too. See w3schools : http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_thead.asp